# Setting up OpenGL in Swift 3

Tags: opengl, swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra

I've a venerable app that I've coerced from the Apple example code GLEssentials in obj-c to Swift 2 and now I'm trying to move to Swift 3. It has a NSOpenGLView at it's core, the main renderer is still not in Swift (I know: I'll have to bite the bullet soon and migrate to Metal or suchlike), but everything else is.

Currently in OSX 10.12, with Xcode 8 the window is just blank. I've had to make some compiler-suggested changes to the main (Swift) OpenGLView class to get it to compile and run succesfully in Swift 3, and I feel this is where the problem lies as the renderer class appears to be running just fine; I can get it to report an FPS of 60 and am able to place breakpoints that do halt the code every frame. My OpenGLView class sets up as below, and this is where most of the new Swift 3 changes have taken place:

```
class BQSOpenGLView: NSOpenGLView {  
    var m_renderer: OpenGLRenderer = OpenGLRenderer()  
    var have_setup_renderer: Bool = false  
    var displayLink: CVDisplayLink?  
    var has_setup = false  
    var is_fullscreen: Bool = false  
    var grid_size: QSGridSize = QSMakeGridSize(1, 1)  
    var backing_scalar_changed: Bool = false  
    var backing_scalar: GLfloat = 0.0  

override func awakeFromNib() {  
        backing_scalar = GLfloat((self.window?.backingScaleFactor)!)  
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BQSOpenGLView.willEnterFullscreen(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWindowWillEnterFullScreen, object: nil)  
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BQSOpenGLView.willExitFullscreen(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWindowWillExitFullScreen, object: nil)  
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BQSOpenGLView.backingScaleChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWindowDidChangeBackingProperties, object: nil)  
        let attributes : [NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute] = [  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer),  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(NSOpenGLPFADepthSize),  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(24),  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(NSOpenGLPFASampleBuffers),  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(1),  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(NSOpenGLPFASamples),  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(2),  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile),  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core),  
            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(0)  
        ]  
        self.pixelFormat = NSOpenGLPixelFormat(attributes: attributes)  
        self.wantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface = true  
        let context:NSOpenGLContext = NSOpenGLContext.init(format: self.pixelFormat!, share: nil)!  
        CGLEnable(context.cglContextObj!, kCGLCECrashOnRemovedFunctions)  
        self.openGLContext = context  
    }  

override func prepareOpenGL() {  
super.prepareOpenGL()  

//  The callback function is called everytime CVDisplayLink says its time to get a new frame.  
        func displayLinkOutputCallback(_ displayLink: CVDisplayLink, _ inNow: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>, _ inOutputTime: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>, _ flagsIn: CVOptionFlags, _ flagsOut: UnsafeMutablePointer<CVOptionFlags>, _ displayLinkContext: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> CVReturn {  
            unsafeBitCast(displayLinkContext, to: BQSOpenGLView.self).renderFrame()  
            return kCVReturnSuccess  
        }  
        self.wantsLayer = true  
        self.wantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface = true  
        CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&displayLink)  
        let success = CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink!, displayLinkOutputCallback, Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())  
        if success != kCVReturnSuccess {  
            Swift.print ("No opengl")  
        }  
        CVDisplayLinkStart(displayLink!)  
        has_setup = true  
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: kOPENGL_SETUP_NOTE), object: nil)  
        self.backingScaleChange(nil)  
    }  
//..  
}
```

The render method is:

```
func renderFrame() {   
     self.openGLContext?.makeCurrentContext()  
     CGLLockContext((self.openGLContext?.cglContextObj)!)  
     if !have_setup_renderer { //init only when locked all the context  
          self.backingScaleChange(nil)  
          m_renderer = OpenGLRenderer.init(defaultFBO: 0, screenSize: (self.window?.screen?.frame.size)!, backingScalar: self.backing_scalar)  
          have_setup_renderer = true  
     }  
     m_renderer.render()  
     CGLFlushDrawable((self.openGLContext?.cglContextObj)!)  
     CGLUnlockContext((self.openGLContext?.cglContextObj)!)  
}
```

Is there a new Swift 3 way of setting up OpenGL or is the above code correct and the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to have been a subtly corrupt Xcode project. The only thing that didn't work was the OpenGL view. Perhaps just the nib was bad.

I started a new project and cut + paste'd the code into new files and laboriously rebuilt the UI and all worked just fine. That'll teach me not to set up the windows programmatically!